# l = e('<div class="vSlide-markers"></div>'); - How do I put this div inside a parent via javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Okay I have a slider on my page. The bullet points that you select to change which slide is currently in view is what im  trying to mess with.

There is no html for them inside the html document. Instead it is displayed in an "ol" tag on the page via javascript.

I changed the ol tag to a div tag since i need it to be inside a div. This worked fine. But i need it to be inside 2 divs.

**So instead of:**

```
l = e('
  <div class="vControllerWrapper"></div>
');
```

**I need:**

```
l = e('
  <div class="vControllerWrapper"> 
    <div class="vSlide-markers"></div>
  </div>
 ');
```

I am just not familiar enough with javascript yet to know how the syntax should be organized to call-in/display 2 divs instead of one.

**Here is the full snippet:**

```
T = function() {
            l = e('<div class="vSlide-markers"></div>');
            e.each(o, function(t, n) {
                var i = t + 1,
                    s = t + 1;
                r.animtype === "slide" && (s = t + 2);
                var o = e('<li><a href="#">' + i + "</a></li>");
                i === v.currentslide && o.addClass("active-marker");
                o.on("click", "a", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    !v.animating && v.currentslide !== s && O(!1, s)
                });
                o.appendTo(l)
            });
```

Any help would be super awesome!

Comment: Not so clear about what you need.

Comment: The javascript is the only thing that brings the <div class="vSlide-markers"></div> onto the page. You can see that div in the second line of javascript. Instead of bringing in ONE div I need it to bring in the div inside of another div IE: parent.

Comment: So I have this: l = e('<div class="vSlide-markers"></div>');

But i need this: l = e('<div class="vControllerWrapper"> <div class="vSlide-markers"></div></div>');

But it doesnt work when i put 2 divs inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines (keep other lines not changed):

```
l = e('<div class="vSlide-markers"></div>');

// Add these two lines
var p = e('<div class="vControllerWrapper"></div>');
l.appendTo(p);

...
```

Similar to your `o.appendTo(l)`, create a parent element and append your element `l` to it.

Comment: Do i keep the vControllerWrapper divs or remove them from the  l = e(' '); ?

Could you possibly re-post your solution with the entire snippet I posted included?

Thanks so much for the help Joy!

Comment: I followed your instructions but am still not getting a div displayed on the page. It still had no parent when inspecting it.

_edit_

Ill add that It does have a class with width/height/backgroundcolor so I can see if it displays or not.

Comment: If i switch it from l.appendTo(p); to p.appendTo(l); it works!! Ill play with it more and see if I can get it to work!  Will post solution soon.

Thanks for all the help